# How to append GET parameters to elastic-search when using tire

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, tire

I wish to append the parameter `?search_type=count` to elastic-search.

```
curl -XGET 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/votes/_search?search_type=count'  -d '
{
   "facets" : {
      "votes" : {
         "terms" : {
            "field" : "question_id"
         }
      }
   }
}'
```

Something like that. How do I tell tire to append that `search_type=count`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`search_type=count` queries is not supported yet in tire, workaround noted in [github issue](https://github.com/karmi/tire/issues/100) is to set size 0.

Comment: Yes, exactly. I think we'll have `_count` queries soon.